# Creating recursive functions using `SetDelayed` and `MapThread`

Tags: function-construction

**EDIT:** I have slightly modified the question to include recursive function.

I want to create some recursive functions using `SetDelayed` within `MapThread`.

```
MapThread[SetDelayed, {{c[x_],f[y_]}, {c[x] = Simplify[x^2 + 3*x - x*(2*x - 7) + c[x - 1]],f[y] = Simplify[E^y - 5*y^2 + y*(y - 1) + f[y + 1]]}}];
```

As expected it simplifies first then applies `SetDelayed`with the LHS.
But I like to have outputs like the followings

```
c[x_] := c[x] = Simplify[x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + c[x - 1]]
f[y_] := f[y] = Simplify[E^y - 5 y^2 + y (y - 1) + f[y + 1]]
```

How is it possible to keep `Simplify[]` unevaluated in `MapThread[]`? For better understanding I have also attached a screen shot.

[image]

As seen from the picture, the recursive function definition is also quite different while using `MapThread[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MapThread[]` is the right idea; using it twice is a little wasteful, when you can use a three-argument function instead to set up the memoization:

```
Remove[c, f];
MapThread[(#1 := (#2 = #3)) &,
          {{c[x_], f[x_]}, {c[x], f[x]},
           {x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + c[x - 1], E^x - 5 x^2 + x (x - 1) + f[x + 1]}}]
```

If the `Simplify[]` is necessary:

```
MapThread[(#1 := (#2 = Simplify[#3])) &,
          {{c[x_], f[x_]}, {c[x], f[x]},
           {x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + c[x - 1], E^x - 5 x^2 + x (x - 1) + f[x + 1]}}]
```

and this approach is of course easily extensible:

```
MapThread[(#1 := (#2 = #3[#4])) &,
          {{c[x_], f[x_]}, {c[x], f[x]}, {Expand, Simplify},
           {x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + c[x - 1], E^x - 5 x^2 + x (x - 1) + f[x + 1]}}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really the correct way of writing a code.

Answer (score 0):

[`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) can provide the closed-form definitions of `c` and `f`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The recursive definitions for `c` and `f` are

```
cr[0] = c0;
cr[x_Integer?Positive] := cr[x] = Simplify[
    x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + cr[x - 1]];
cr[x_Integer?Negative] := cr[x] = Simplify[
    cr[x + 1] - (x + 1)^2 - 3 (x + 1) + (x + 1) (2 (x + 1) - 7)];

fr[0] = f0;
fr[x_Integer?Positive] := fr[x] = Simplify[
    fr[x - 1] - E^(x - 1) + 5 (x - 1)^2 - (x - 1) (x - 2)];
fr[x_Integer?Negative] := fr[x] = Simplify[
    E^x - 5 x^2 + x (x - 1) + fr[x + 1]];
```

Using `RSolve` to obtain the closed-form expressions

```
sol = RSolve[{c[x] == x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + c[x - 1],
      f[x] == E^x - 5 x^2 + x (x - 1) + f[x + 1],
      c[0] == c0, f[0] == f0}, {c[x], f[x]}, x][[1]] //
   FullSimplify;

c[x_] = c[x] /. sol

(* c0 - 1/6 x (1 + x) (-29 + 2 x) *)

f[x_] = f[x] /. sol

(* (1/(6 (-1 + E)))(6 - 6 E^x - 6 f0 + x (-1 + (9 - 8 x) x) + 
  E (6 f0 + (-1 + x) x (-1 + 8 x))) *)
```

Checking that the recursive and closed-forms are equivalent for integer arguments

```
And @@ Table[c[x] == cr[x] && f[x] == fr[x], {x, -20, 20}] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Plotting with `c0 == 0` and `f0 == 0`

```
Show[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[{c[x], f[x]} /. {c0 -> 0, f0 -> 0}],
  {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{c, f}, {0.6, 0.8}]],
 DiscretePlot[{
   cr[x] /. {c0 -> 0, f0 -> 0},
   fr[x] /. {c0 -> 0, f0 -> 0}},
  {x, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle ->
   {Darker@Blue, {Thick, Orange, Dashed}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not want to solve the recursive function. Actually I have a list of expressions which have come from series of calculation and are stored in a variable, say `exp`. I want to use each of those expressions enclosed within `Simplify[]` to create recursive functions which will be used in subsequent calculation. I believe `Simplify[]` will make the expression of `f[n]` much simplified prior to using it for the calculation of `f[n+1]`. Hence, I posted a simple example only for seeking solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible solution

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Ex = {x^2 + 3 x - x (2 x - 7) + c[x - 1], 
   E^x - 5 x^2 + x (x - 1) + f[x + 1]};
MapThread[
   OP1, {{c[x_], f[x_]}, 
    MapThread[
     OP2, {{c[x], f[x]}, Table[Simp[Ex[[i]]], {i, 2}]}]}] /. {OP1 -> 
    SetDelayed, OP2 -> Set, Simp -> Simplify};
```

[image]